# Creating SQL query in VB.net from a Checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist and I populate it dynamically from a database. For example after i populate the checkboxlist is like that:

- Los Angeles
- New York
- London
- Berlin
- Amsterdam

I want to create a SQL query according to the checkboxes are checked. If i want to choose only one city (e.g. only New York) i want the result to be:

> (City = 2)

Thats works properly but when i have multiple cities (e.g. New York, London and Amsterdam) i want the result to be for example:

> (City = 2) OR (City = 3) OR (City = 5)

Or if i choose Los Angeles and Berlin I want the result to be like this:

> (City = 1) OR (City = 4)

How can i achieve this? That's my code below but I am stacked. Any ideas?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim var As String = ""
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Selected Then
            myList.Add(i + 1)
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter = 1 Then
                var = "(City =" & i + 1 & ")"
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(myList(1))
                Dim myArray As String() = myList.ToArray()
                For j As Integer = 1 To myArray.Length
                    Dim var2 As String = " OR (City =" & counter & ")"
                    var = "(City =" & myArray(0) & ")" & var2
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data1 WHERE (" & var & ") ORDER BY [ID]"
    Session("Search") = SQL
    Server.Transfer("Data_Form.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: What you're doing right now is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Please learn about query parameters. Especially what will help you right away is Table-value Parameters.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's valuable input but it's not *that* vulnerable given that the `var` variable never seem to contain end user input. Plus it's harder to build a custom where condition with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `City IN(2,3,5)` instead of `(City = 2) OR (City = 3) OR (City = 5)`:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim condition As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Selected Then
            condition = condition & "," & (i + 1)
        End If
    Next
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Data1 WHERE (" & condition.SubString(1) & ") ORDER BY [ID]"
    Session("Search") = SQL
    Server.Transfer("Data_Form.aspx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What I recommend most strongly is to look into Table-value Parameters:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

This will fix your issue and help you avoid sql injection vulnerabilities.

But if you really insist on using string concatenation, try using an `IN()` condition, where you end up with something more like `CITY IN (1,2)` instead of `(City = 1 OR City = 2)`. You can make this a bit easier to write by leading with an unused ID, like so:

```vb
Dim cityClause As String = " CITY IN (-1{0})" 'start with a valid clause
Dim cityIDs As String = ""
For Each box As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items.Where(Function(b) b.Selected)
     'Try storing the ID for each city in the value part of each listitem,
     ' rather than using the index order 
     cityIDs = cityIDs & "," & box.Value
Next box
cityClause = string.Format(cityClause, cityIDs)
```

Comment: +1 for mentionning table-valued parameters, although this will only work with Sql Server 2012 and above.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Avoid what SQL injection vulnerabilities? His code does not have any SQL injection vulnerabilities. Besides, although your usage of `box.Value` is more standard, that's not what he asked for. He's using the index and that's what he asked for. If you're offering him a different approach, you need to explain to him why he would want to change his way.

Comment: @RacilHilan The technique in general is vulnerable, and should be avoided everywhere simply out of good practices.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Please give me a break. I don't know what "technique" and "good practices" you're referring to. I've never heard of them. Are you telling me now that if I have a query like `SELECT x,y,z FROM t WHERE active=1`, then it's vulnerable and I have to pass `active` in a parameter? Seriously? Can you please either provide links and references to support what you're saying? Otherwise, please consider correcting your comments. Parameterized queries are there for a reason, not to use them blindly everywhere just because they're better.

Comment: @Crono TVPs were introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @RacilHilan While I agree that in this *particular* scenario it's unlikely that the code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, Joel still does make a valid point. And yes, if you did pass your `active` value as a string concatenated to your query string, the code *could* be at risk depending on where the value comes from. So yes, it's safer to make it a parameter instead. Rule of thumb: do not trust input from outside the code scope.

Comment: @Crono That's what I was asking for. It's not very useful to just say something without a good explanation. Your explanation is the minimum required. It my example, the value is not coming from anywhere and it's not concatenated, its hardcoded, so it is NOT at any kind of risk whatsoever. Similarly, the code from the OP is not at any kind of risk. Not until he decides to use the value instead of the index like Joel suggested. But even then, if the values are numerical IDs and you convert them to integers (in business layer?) before concatenating them into your SQL, then there is still no risk.

Comment: @RacilHilan I understand and to some extend I agree with you but then again the OP is asking for a working solution, not a lecture. Being brief on potential pitfalls seen in the original code *may* be of help to the OP. Too much details on that, however, can completely obscure the answer he immediately need. Plus, Joel *did* provide an example using concatenation, so honestly I believe his answer is appropriate as it is. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Crono I agree with you, except for the fact that Joel neither offered an explanation nor a "working solution". He offered using the value instead of the index without any explanation. How can we assume that the value has anything in it if the OP did not set it? Yes, the OP was asking for a working solution, not a lecture, but Joel's answer (and comments) was more like a lecture lacking explanation, and definitely not a working solution.

Comment: @RacilHilan Ah, you're correct, I see it now. Yes, he is using `box.Value` and yes it might not be appropriate.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I suggest you edit your answer so that it either explain why and how `box.Value` should be used or make usage of combobox items index instead.